# UI Animations Jquery vs AngularJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, animation

I am developing a web app and using AngularJS. But, until now, I have no UI animations. I'm wondering to use jQuery or AngularJS to make the animations.

I know that AngularJS has ngAnimate directive, as I can build my own directive, but there are a lot of good animations in jQuery and a lot of good examples. Why should I make UI Animations using AngularJS? Only to keep the AngularJS standard in my code? Or there are more than that?

Is common to always use AngularJS for all animations when we are talking about an AngularJS web app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using angular's MVVM methodology when binding your data to your UI,  angular-animate would be much much simpler and more intuitive.
Depends on the animations you want to have..     Using angular-animate you could easily do things like:  stagger animation for ng-repeat items on entry, leave and move (different for each).   easy with angular-animate,  but could be hard without,  again - depends on your animations, how you access and modify data ,etc..

Answer (score 1):

Angular-animate allows you to easily:

1. Use existing CSS classes that built-in angular directives use whenever they manipulate the DOM: .enter, .leave, .enter-active, .leave-active etc.  You can easily add CSS 3 transitions to animate when items are added or removed from an ng-repeat, for example.
2. Use scripting libraries to do the animations (jquery, tweenmax, etc).  This is also CSS class driven.